# Map props to state for react toolbox input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-toolbox

React toolbox seem to require I use state for its input values http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/input. How can I map my redux props to state for use with `react-toolbox`?

```
<Input type='text' 
    label='Name' 
    name='name' 
    value={this.state.name} 
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
```

I think if I set it in constructor when redux state changes, it will not update my state?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to map redux states to component props.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  inputBoxValue: state.myReduer.inputBoxValue,
});
```

2. Then we can bind the props to the component using

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myComponent);
```

3. And we can use It in our component like regular props.

```
<Input type='text' 
            label='Name' 
            name='name' 
            value={this.props.name} 
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
```

Redux doc: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Please let me know If I'm missing something?